# Error Deserializing xml file with XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I'm trying to deserialize an xml with XmlSerializer and I get 
InvalidOperationException:  was not expected.
Here's the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
    <ArrayOfplatform xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <platform>
    <positionX></positionX>
    <positionY></positionY>
    <moveSpeed>10</moveSpeed>
    <ID>1</ID>
  </platform>
</ArrayOfplatform>
```

And the classes

```
public class platform : gameElement 
{
    //[Serializable] 
    private float moveSpeed;
    public int ID;
}
public class gameElement
{   
    //[Serializable]
    public float positionX, positionY;
}
```

If it matters, I'm trying to read stuff for a platformer game made in Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're couple of problems with your XML:

1. Array serialization format is wrong for `XmlSerializer` - element name should be `ArrayOfPlatform` instead of `ArrayOfplatform`. (uppercase P)
2. `platform.moveSpeed` is private in your class and cannot be serialized or deserialized with `XmlSerializer`.
3. `positionX, positionY` are of type `float` (value-type) and cannot have empty values in the XML. Should be `0`.

Fix that, everything else is fine.